# How to make text triangle text box

Tags: java, palindrome

```
// The "PalinDrome" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class PalinDrome
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();

        c.println("Please enter a word");
           String word = c.readLine ();
        int i;
        int num = word.length ();
        String str = "";
        for (i = num - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
            str = str + word.charAt (i);
        if (str.equals (word))
            c.println (word + " is a palindrome");
        else
            c.println (word + " is not a palindrome");

        str.equalsIgnoreCase(word);




        // Place your program here.  'c' is the output console
    } // main method
} // PalinDrome class
```

I have created a palindrome program as part of my exam project. I would like for the letters to appear in the shape of a triangle. Do you have any suggestions on how i can do that?

Comment: Rather than expensively creating a new string each time with character concatenation, you should use StringUtils to reverse the string and concatenate just the once onto the original.

Answer (score 0):

user `string.format` to build a triangular form with `&nbsp;` `\t` and `\n` depending on the length of the string. use another `for` loop to run through the string and append the appropriate spacing before/after every set of characters